# Vue transition group not render list item

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

template:
[image]

methods: 
[image]

In chrome: Not any list item rander only the transition-group tag tranform to section tag. And in console nothing error occurs.
[image]

Actually when I remove transition-group tag and wrap a section tag, it should have render view like this:
[image]

Please tell me what goes wrong exactly? thx.

Comment: Hi, the first two images with the JS and HTML code you should add to the question as text, formatted with the code tag. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

add `:key="index"` attribute where you v-for the items

Comment: thx.It fix that.Can you tell me why it works when add :key=index ?

Comment: transition-group needs it to know to which forEach item to add the class for the specified time, because you may want to animate them as waterfall but vue doesn't know your css so it needs it. Something like this Im not really sure